# grails: How to disable resizable property of <s2ui:form> tag

Tags: java, jquery, grails

When using the `<s2ui:form>` tag the page showing the **div** generated by spring security with resizable property as shown in the screenshot.
[Image screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTQdt.png)

i want to to disable the option but the `<s2ui:form>` is processed after the `document.ready()`.
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Best bet is to copy/extend the taglib and override any functionality that you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize some aspects of the plugin with the `s2ui-override` [script](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-ui/v3/index.html#s2ui-override-script)

Answer (score 0):

Got it. The `<s2ui:form>` have the attribute `resizeable` set its as `false` resolved my issue.

```
<s2ui:form width='475' height='250' elementId='formContainer' center='true' resizeable="false">
```